# Apache Rewrite for Domain Canonicalization & HTTPS

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I have tried to piece together some suggestions found both here and elsewhere on using mod_rewrite to ensure `www.` as well as `https://` on a site. I've come up with the following solution, but am curious if there is a more concise way to achieve the same goal.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

</VirtualHost>
```

Note that in my present use case I'm only trying to change the following cases:

- `http://domain.com` -> `https://www.domain.com`
- `http://www.domain.com` -> `https://www.domain.com`
- `https://domain.com` -> `https://www.domain.com`

There are other subdomains that I do not want to redirect to `https://`, so I am only trying to match requests for the raw domain and the `www` subdomain. Any insight would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

All-in-one:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}_%{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*_domain\.com|off_www\.domain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```